# Sequelize query with a where clause on an include of an include

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm struggling to create a query with sequelize.

**Some context**

I have the following models:

- A `Manifestation` can have [0..n] `Event`
- An `Event` belongs to one `Manifestation` (an `Event` cannot exist without a `Manifestation`)
- A `Place` can have [0..n] `Event`
- An `Event` belongs to one `Place` (an `Event` cannot exist without a `Place`)
- A `Manifestation` can have [1..n] `Place`
- A `Place` can have [0..n] `Manifestation`

I model the relations as the following:

```js
Manifestation.hasMany(Event, { onDelete: 'CASCADE', hooks: true })
Event.belongsTo(Manifestation)

Place.hasMany(Event, { onDelete: 'CASCADE', hooks: true })
Event.belongsTo(Place)

Manifestation.belongsToMany(Place, { through: 'manifestation_place' })
Place.belongsToMany(Manifestation, { through: 'manifestation_place' })
```

For me it seems rather correct, but don't hesitate if you have remarks.

**The question**

I'm trying to query the `Place` in order to get all `Manifestation` and `Event` happening in a given `Place`. But for the `Event` ones, I want to include them within their `Manifestation` even if the `Manifestation` doesn't happen in the given `Place`.

Below is the "JSON" structure I'm trying to achieve:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Place Name",
  address: "Place address",
  latitude: 47.00000,
  longitude: -1.540000,
  manifestations: [
    {
      id: 10,
      title: "Manifestation one",
      placeId: 1,
      events: []
    },
    {
      id: 11,
      title: "Manifestation two",
      placeId: 3,
      events: [
        id: 5,
        title: "3333",
        manifestationId: 11,
        placeId: 1
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So I want to include the `Manifestation` with `id`: 11, because one of its `Event` occurs in the given `Place` (with `id`: 1)

**Update (04/06/20): For now I rely on javascript to get the expected result**

I figured out it would be nice if I posted my current solution before asking.

```
router.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const placesPromise = place.findAll()
    const manifestationsPromise = manifestation.findAll({
      include: [
        { model: event },
        {
          model: place,
          attributes: ['id'],
        },
      ],
    })

    const [places, untransformedManifestations] = await Promise.all([
      placesPromise,
      manifestationsPromise,
    ])

    const manifestations = untransformedManifestations.map(m => {
      const values = m.toJSON()
      const places = values.places.map(p => p.id)
      return { ...values, places }
    })

    const result = places
      .map(p => {
        const values = p.toJSON()
        const relatedManifestations = manifestations
          .filter(m => {
            const eventsPlaceId = m.events.map(e => e.placeId)
            return (
              m.places.includes(values.id) ||
              eventsPlaceId.includes(values.id)
            )
          })
          .map(m => {
            const filteredEvents = m.events.filter(
              e => e.placeId === values.id
            )
            return { ...m, events: filteredEvents }
          })
        return { ...values, manifestations: relatedManifestations }
      })
      .filter(p => p.manifestations.length)

    return res.status(200).json(result)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return res.status(500).send()
  }
})
```

But I'm pretty sure I could do that directly with sequelize. Any ideas or recommendations ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not optimum. But you can try it out:

```
const findPlace = (id) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        db.Place.findOne({
            where: {
                id: id
            }
        }).then(place => {
            db.Manefestation.findAll({
                include: [{
                    model: db.Event,
                    where: {
                        placeId: id
                    }
                }]

            }).then(manifestations => {
                const out = Object.assign({}, {
                    id: place.id,
                    name: place.name,
                    address: place.address,
                    latitude: place.latitude,
                    longitude: place.longitude,
                    manifestations: manifestations.reduce((res, manifestation) => {
                        if (manifestation.placeId === place.id || manifestation.Event.length > 0) {
                            res.push({
                                id: manifestation.id,
                                title: manifestation.id,
                                placeId: manifestation.placeId,
                                events: manifestation.Event
                            })
                        }
                        return res;
                    }, [])
                })
            })
            resolve(out);
        })
    })
}
```

From this, you get all manifestations that assigned to place or have any event that assigns. All included events in the manefestations are assigned to the place.

**Edit :**
You will be able to use the following one too:

```
const findPlace = (id) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        db.Place.findOne({
            include: [{
                model: db.Manefestation,
                include: [{
                    model: db.Event,
                    where: {
                        placeId: id
                    }
                }]

            }],
            where: {
                id: id
            }
        }).then(place => {
            db.Manefestation.findAll({
                include: [{
                    model: db.Event,
                    where: {
                        placeId: id
                    }
                }],
                where: {
                    placeId: {
                        $not: id
                    }
                }

            }).then(manifestations => {
                place.Manefestation = place.Manefestation.concat(manifestations.filter(m=>m.Event.length>0))
                resolve(place);// or you can rename, reassign keys here
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Here I take only direct manifestations in the first query. Then, manifestations that not included and concatenate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's what I actually do, and I was looking for a sequelize way of doing it instead of a plain js one.

Comment: you can execute db query SQL though

Comment: After looking at your solution, it does not do what I'm looking for too. Re-read carefully my question

Comment: There were some typos in the first answer and I edited it. Also, I added a new answer too

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, I added one big missing part on my question: my current solution, which is more or less the same that you provide. But I'm looking for a "full" sequelize way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you figure it out by now. But the solution is provided below.
Search with Sequelize could get funny :). You have to include inside another include. If the query gets slow use `separate:true`.

```
Place.findAll({
          include: [           
            {
              model: Manifestation,
              attributes: ['id'],
              include: [{ 
              model: Event ,
              attributes: ['id']
               }]
            },
           ],
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to complete it in a single query but you will still need JavaScript to be able to get the type of output that you want.

(Note:  You need manifestation which is not connected to places but should be included if a event is present of that place. The only SQL way to get that starts by doing a CROSS JOIN between all tables and then filtering out the results which will be a very hefty query)

---

I came up with this code(tried & executed) which doesn't need you to execute 2 findAll that fetches all data as what you are currently using. Instead it fetched only the data needed for final output in 1 query.

```js
const places = await Place.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Manifestation,
        // attributes: ['id']
        through: {
            attributes: [], // this helps not get keys/data of join table
        },
    }, {
        model: Event,
        include: [{
            model: Manifestation,
            // attributes: ['id']
        }],
    }
    ],
});
console.log('original output places:', JSON.stringify(places, null, 2));

const result = places.map(p => {
    // destructuring to separate out place, manifestation, event object keys
    const {
        manifestations,
        events,
        ...placeData
    } = p.toJSON();

    // building modified manifestation with events array
    const _manifestations = manifestations.map(m => {
        return ({ ...m, events: [] })
    });

    // going through places->events to push them to respective manifestation events array
    // + add manifestation which is not directly associated to place but event is of that manifestation
    events.map(e => {
        const {
            manifestation: e_manifestation, // renaming variable
            ...eventData
        } = e;
        const mIndex = _manifestations.findIndex(m1 => m1.id === e.manifestationId)
        if (mIndex === -1) { // if manifestation not found add it with the events array
            _manifestations.push({ ...e_manifestation, events: [eventData] });
        } else { // if found push it into events array
            _manifestations[mIndex].events.push(eventData);
        }
    });
    // returning a place object with manifestations array that contains events array
    return ({ ...placeData, manifestations: _manifestations });
})
// filter `.filter(p => p.manifestations.length)` as used in your question
console.log('modified places', JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```